# Display multiple prj site in one view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

Suppose I've 3 prj sites which is used to maintain a prj task

- Prj A
- Prj B
- Prj C

And in each prj, they have their task

Prj A
  - Task A.1
 Prj B
  - Task B.1
 Prj C
  - Task C.1

Is it possible to have a view which can display all the prj tasks in one view where Gantt view is also supported?

I've tried to combine 3 data sources into one. However, I can only use the combined source to create a very fundamental view (just a plain table only). Is there any way to display it in a "traditional prj task" way?

Or said in another way, is it possible to change the data source of a Prj task? If so, can I then change the Prj Task data source to my combined data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [OOTB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box) it is not possible to show a Gantt chart for the multiple list view. Either you can create your custom webpart or look for a third party solution.